# How to set processes parameter in oracle 11g Windows in accordance with RAM in the server

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, windows-server, process, session

Could anyone explain me whether there is any limitation in setting **processes** parameter in Oracle 11gr2 and how to set sga_target according to this.

Right now I have set the processes to 4000 and I have around 300 to 400 users using the database.

My server is running using Win2012 R2 and 32GB of RAM.

Any help will be appreciated.